# How convert rotate3d xaml to c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want rotate a button in 3d view in WPF
I google it and found this 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168420/wpf-rotating-button)

but I want do it in c# behind code
how can I convert this XAML storyboard code to c# behind code that when clicked on button rotate it around z axis

```
<Viewport3D>
<Viewport3D.Camera>
    <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4"/>
</Viewport3D.Camera>
<Viewport2DVisual3D x:Name="v2dv3d">
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
        <RotateTransform3D>
            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
        </RotateTransform3D>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
        <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
    <Button Content="Hello, 3D">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <Rotation3DAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="v2dv3d"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform).(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"
                                                Duration="0:0:2"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0">
                            <Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                            </Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                            <Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                            </Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                        </Rotation3DAnimation>
                        <Rotation3DAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="v2dv3d"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform).(RotateTransform3D.Rotation)"
                                                Duration="0:0:2"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:2">
                            <Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="-90" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                            </Rotation3DAnimation.From>
                            <Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                            </Rotation3DAnimation.To>
                        </Rotation3DAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Viewport2DVisual3D>
<ModelVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
        <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
</ModelVisual3D>
```

tnx

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591106/create-a-blink-animation-in-wpf-in-code-behind

Comment: I know how to convert simple storyboard to c# code but my problem is with this complex storyboard is there any specific trick for convert this to c# code exist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, you have to write everything you need for your storyboard in code behind.